# I need to implement an action to double click and then open a new window. (sigma.js)

Tags: javascript, function, window.open, sigma.js

I implemented a graphical map using sigma.js and a node content I need to implement an action to double click and then open a new window.

This function, doubleclick, already exists in the library but it is automatic to do zoom. It don't receive no parameter, I need to modify it because for developing that other function I need the url contained in the object.

Anyone help me. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the bind method and take action 
    
    `s.bind('doubleClickNode', function(e) {
      // console.log(e.type, e.data.node.label, e.data.captor);
      // now open new window for your purpose
    });`

hope it helps